# Can newton's third law be said as a macroscopic consequence of coulomb's law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics

When two atoms are very, when they are in contact in the macroscopic perspective, there will be repulsion and attraction between electrons and protons.

When two objects are away this is not a problem as net charge is zero.

So, from these can we say that newton's third law is a consequence of coulomb's law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proton repels another proton - it experiences the same push the opposite way. It attracts an electron - and experiences the same pull the opposite way. *This* is the 3rd law. Coulomb's law talks about the size of this repelling/attracting force, but Newton's 3rd law says that both experience it. These are two difference concepts.

Comment: Moreover N3 is not limited to E&M.

Comment: Yes, @Steeven , what I am asking is whether the reaction is a result of the coulombic  interactions.

Comment: @Allen The reaction is, yes. Coulombic interactions are why we see repulsion or attraction.

Comment: But Allan, note @ZeroTheHero's comment - saying that Newton's 3rd law is a consequence of coulombic interactions can be quickly dismissed since we know that the 3rd law also holds for e.g. gravitational forces.